# c# - is there anything like BeforeLastIndexOf?

Tags: c#, indexof, lastindexof

I wanted to know if there is anything like "`BeforeLastIndexOf`". I'm new to c# and don't really know how "`LastIndexOf`" and "`IndexOf`" works. What I'm trying to achive is that for example the user types in a directory and it deletes from the string the last folder of this directory but usually directory's look like this "`C:\something\something\`" and it has a `"\"` at the end, so a code like this doesn't work:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int index = input.LastIndexOf("/");
if (index > 0)
     input = input.Substring(0, index + 1);
```

Cause it deletes only everything after the last `"\"` and it's anyway at the end so it doesn't delete anything

Comment: Do you want [`Directory.Delete(input, true);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx)? This will delete the directory specified (which is the "last" folder in the path), regardless of a trailing slash.

Comment: i mean deleting it from the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to:

1. Remove any trailing backslashes, using `string.TrimEnd()`.
2. Call `Path.GetDirectoryName()` to strip off the last directory.

For example:

```
string path1 = @"C:\something\something\";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path1.TrimEnd('\\'))); // Prints "C:\something

string path2 = @"C:\something\something";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path2.TrimEnd('\\'))); // Prints "C:\something
```

If you want to handle `/` characters too (since that's actually a valid path separator in Windows), you can just specify both in the `TrimEnd()`:

```
path1.TrimEnd('/', '\\')
```

Thus:

```
string path3 = @"C:/something/something//\\/";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path3.TrimEnd('/', '\\'))); // Prints "C:\something
```

Comment: What you are doing is a kludge. You're pretending like the last segment in the path name is a file name, but it's a directory name. I don't think that hacking .NET is the good way to write software. The proper way to do this is to use `Directory` or `DirectoryInfo` to parse the entire path.

Comment: @ZoranHorvat It's not a kludge. [The documentation for `Path.GetDirectoryName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) specifically describes this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're missing the point with your question. If you want to manipulate directory paths, then you should use types from the `System.IO` namespace and let them do that right. For example, finding the immediate parent directory given a full path of a directory can be done like this:

```
string parentPath = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath).Parent.FullName;
```

If you still want to do that on your own, then there's an overload of `LastIndexOf` which accepts the range within which to search (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0z3tk9t(v=vs.110).aspx). However, you have to make sure not to access nonexistent indices within the string.

```
string final = input;
int secondLast = input.LastIndexOf("/");
if (secondLast >= 0)
{
    secondLast = input.LastIndexOf("/", secondLast - 1, secondLast);
}

if (secondLast >= 0)
{
    final = input.Substring(0, secondLast + 1); // Includes final '/'
}
```

When this code executes, the `secondLast` variable will either be set to `-1`, or to the index of the second last occurrence of `/`. Note that the variable will also be set to `-1` if there is one appearance of `/`, but not the second one to precede it.

Comment: LastInputOf doesn't exist

Comment: Fixed, it was a typo in the second call.

Comment: thats right but yours doesn't work either cause nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TrimEnd` before doing anything else

```
 input = input.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

This will remove last directory separator ‘/‘ character. After this you can use your further logic to work with path.

Comment: This would needlessly construct an entire new string.

Comment: It will just remove the last unwanted character. And ofCourse new string that you can use further in your logic. If you want same variable then assign back to input. Edited answer @ZoranHorvat

Comment: @ZoranHorvat - Strings are immutable, any change will create a new string.

Comment: @Null511 That's my point - this step would needlessly construct a new string without producing what was required.